# Split a String by Regex Expression - Split the whole String by the Character '=' only if the Character on the left is not # in Kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin, split

e.g.
If i have a String like `val input = "2+2#=4=test2"` should return a List

> 1. 2+2#=4
> 2. test2

order is not important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try splitting using a lookbehind which asserts that what precedes the `=` sign is *not* a hash symbol:

```kotlin
val input = "2+2#=4=test2";
val arr = input.split("(?<!#)=".toRegex());
println(arr);
```

This prints:

```
[2+2#=4, test2]
```